# PHP - using strip_tags to REMOVE text between removed tags

Tags: php, strip-tags

I have this sample code:

```
<?php

$string='Left text from tag <div title="hello world" class="CSS">What is <b>going on</b> here?<br> Calm up <em>right now</em>.</div> Right text. Possible another <div title="" class="DD">tag..</div> but not always.';

echo strip_tags($string);
?>
```

The result of this code is:

```
Left text from tag What is going on here? Calm up right now. Right text. Possible another tag.. but not always.
```

However, my goal is to REMOVE all text (including tags) between the tags removed by this strip_tags function. Ie. the result should be:

```
Left text from tag Right text. Possible another but not always.
```

I know it can be done with preg_replace, but it's too slow so maybe there is a faster solution.. (not necessarily related to strip_tags function).

Answer (score 3):

Using REGEX is the best and most compact solution in my opinion. Try this:

```
echo preg_replace('@<(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $string);
```

If you don't want to use preg_replace, use the customized function [strip_tags_content()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php#86964) mentioned in the manual.

```
function strip_tags_content($text, $tags = '', $invert = FALSE) { 

    preg_match_all('/<(.+?)[\s]*\/?[\s]*>/si', trim($tags), $tags); 
    $tags = array_unique($tags[1]); 

    if(is_array($tags) AND count($tags) > 0) { 
        if($invert == FALSE) { 
            return preg_replace('@<(?!(?:'. implode('|', $tags) .')\b)(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text); 
         } else { 
             return preg_replace('@<('. implode('|', $tags) .')\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text); 
         } 
     } elseif($invert == FALSE) { 
           return preg_replace('@<(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text); 
     } 
     return $text; 
 } 

echo strip_tags_content($string);
```

Note: I don't think yor desired output could be achieved using PHP functions only. You need to use REGEX in one way or the other.

Comment: Yes, but can it be done without using preg_replace (ie. I need a faster solution..). Since strip_tags knows what to replace so maybe it can be used to remove text between what strip_tags found too..

Comment: I don't think there's any straight forward solution to your problem using PHP in built functions. YOu gotta use REGEX in one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

How about a DOMDocument approach?

```
<?php

$string='Left text from tag <div title="hello world" class="CSS">What is <b>going on</b> here?<br> Calm up <em>right now</em>.</div> Right text. Possible another <div title="" class="DD">tag..</div> but not always.';

$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<body>' . $string . '</body>');

$stripped = '';
$els = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes;
$len = count($els) - 1;
foreach($els as $index => $child) {
    if (is_null($child->tagName))
        $stripped .= ' ' . trim($child->nodeValue);
}
$stripped = substr($stripped, 1);

echo $stripped;
```

[Output](https://eval.in/private/368dbad4aea613):

```
Left text from tag Right text. Possible another but not always.
```

Comment: It could work too (even though now I wonder what is faster, preg_replace or this solution :)